# Completely disable LID sensor events on Ubuntu 20

Tags: power-management, lid

TLDR:  I've tried changing both logind and upower configuration files to ignore lid closing action, I tried disabling it via /proc/acpi/wakeup, I tried gnome tweaks and I checked even if it can be disabled in BIOS.

My lid sensor (Thinkbook 14) is glitchy. I want to disable it, because right now, sometimes it flickers the screen as if it registered a close lid event and become unresponsive till I  interact with the computer, or completely open the windows to flat position.

Is there a way how to completely ignore lid sensor events so that even with the lid closed the screen is on and the computer works as if open? I use the computer as a backup when working from a cabin, therefore it is used as a stationary computer anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu 20??   So you're using Ubuntu Core 20 which is a *headless* server OS on your system?  (desktop systems are available only for Ubuntu products using the *year.month* format, not *year* products)

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry, I thought from information provided it was obvious it is desktop since I am mentioning a specific laptop model.
Also, it is not an issue with specific Ubuntu version, more like issue of finding a way to reliably block lid sensor signals.

Comment: Security differs in the 20 products to 20.04 systems; the large differences between the products are part of why the different release format is used. Loads of people use no-longer needed laptops as servers; so usage of laptop device as a server is very common.  Ubuntu Core 20 though is significant details that needs to be correct (*20 & 20.04 are different products*)

Comment: @ErikCitterberg I can completely see where you are coming from but I suspect you will be closer to a good answer if you change 'Ubuntu 20' in your question to 'Ubuntu 20.04', or whichever release of Ubuntu you are using.